# Difference between init() and onBootStrap() in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm reading a book on ZF2 and it refers to both init() and onBootStrap() as functions in Module.php that are called during every page load and therefore should be as lightweight as possible.

Aside from a slightly different signature:

```
init(ModuleManager m)
onBootStrap(MvcEvent e)
```

I'm struggling to determine when I should use which, and for what reason. In the book, both methods are being used to attach to (different) events. Can someone provide a clear definition of the difference between the two, and some concrete examples where I would use one but not the other (and why)?

Thanks!

Comment: onBootStrap(MvcEvent e) usually listens for events and init(ModuleManager m) for modules. While you can add event's to the ModuleManager it's probably better to do so with the onBootStrap(MvcEvent e).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is a matter of timing and purpose.  The `init()` function always occurs before the `onBootstrap()` function.  Since the purpose of `init()` is to initialize the module (eg. with its own, independent configuration options), other modules may not have been loaded at the time `init()` is run for a given module.  However, `onBootstrap()` is run after all modules have been initialized, and it can listen for different events.

A much more thorough explanation of this can be found at 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html
and the next page in the documentation
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-class.html

Personally, I use the `init()` to initialize a Propel library in one module I creatively named `Propel` by using the technique at http://4zend.com/integrate-propel-orm-with-zend-framework-2/.

I use `onBootstrap()` to check my access control list (which users have access to what resources) and restrict access accordingly, like this:

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e) {
    // After the route event occurs, run the checkAcl method of this class
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach('route', array($this, 'checkAcl'));
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I ended up coming to a very similar conclusion. I struggled to understand why event listeners were being attached from both functions, before I realised the particular event listener being set up from init() actually occurs before onBootstrap() is called.