# How do I call a Module function before Controller loads in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, event-listener

I want a make a call to a module's function before controller loads. How do I go about this? Any ideas/links to this?  I want to learn how to add hook points to control the flow but couldn't get much idea. 
Basically, I want my chat module to appear on all pages of the website. Right now, I have to make a call from every page to load it.
There are various MVC events like bootstrap, render etc. Can any of these come to rescue?

If you need any specific code, do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Module.php`, you could attach a function that should be called when any action is to be rendered -

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;                 

use SOME_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;           //updated line 

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $e->getApplication()
                ->getEventManager()
                ->getSharedManager()
                ->attach('*', 'dispatch', array($this, 'FUNCTION_NAME'));
    }

    public function FUNCTION_NAME(MvcEvent $e) {
        //your code for this function

       $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();


       //Eg:
       $service = new SOME_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME();   //updated lines
       $service->setServiceLocator($sm);
       $service->methodName(); 
    }

    [rest of the code]
}
```

1. `'*'` - says that the function is attached to all the module's controllers.
2. `dispatch` - says the function to be called on dispatch (before render)
3. The `FUNCTION_NAME` function will be called before rendering the view page.

Please read about `getEventManager` and `getSharedManager` and attaching functions to events `onBootstrap` to explore.

**Edit:**
1. `use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;` is added at the top.

1. `$sm` is set to the service.
2. To get it in the service class, the class should have a method -

   protected $serviceLocator;

   public function setServiceLocator($serviceLocator = null) {
       $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
   }

This way when you will call `getServiceLocator()` from within your service class, it will get the service locator.

Comment: If my function is in another file? I made a ModuleService file which has this function.

Comment: In the `FUCNTION_NAME` code, make a object of that service and call the method. Make sure to include the `use ....` statement above the `class Module { ..` line. If the service requires some dependencies then provide them too. Example included in the answer. Please check.

Comment: I did that and it works. But when I try to call this `' $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
             $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable'); `
I get 'Call to a member function get() on a non-object'. Do you know the possible reason?

Comment: ^This is inside the function that gets called.

Comment: Its the dependency that needs to be provided. In the function code write - `$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager(); $service->setServiceLocator($sm);` You do need to have a `setServiceLocator()` method in the service class file.

Comment: I can't use $e in my Service Class File. It is from Zend Mvc class.

Comment: Updated the answer. Get service locator in `Module.php` itself and pass it to the service class file via `setServiceLocator()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works. :D

Answer (score 1):

you had two options: 
`init()` and  `onBootstrap()` , I tend to use `onBootstrap()`

https://github.com/tawfekov/ZF2EntityAudit/blob/master/Module.php
you can check this helpful resources

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550529/109217
2. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-class.html#the-mvc-bootstrap-event

an example of `onBootstrap()`:https://github.com/tawfekov/ZF2EntityAudit/blob/master/Module.php